# Why am I seeing emojis under my "frequently used" section that I've never even used?

Tags: iphone, ios

Recently I've been seeing emojis under the frequently used section that I've never even used before. Is it possible I'm seeing my husbands frequently used emojis on my phone somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The list of frequently used emoji is literally a list of emojis that you've used most often. This list does not synchronise over iCloud. The only other way emojis could be in the list is that the frequent list is pre-populated when restoring iOS with a standard set of emojis.

Comment: it's definitely _not_ the emojis that you use most often.  I've frequently seen only recently used emojis, where most often used emojis are absent from the list

Answer (score -3):

The same thing happened to me.  I was reading on some White Nationalist websites and all of a sudden the Star of David with the dot in the center, a magnifying glass, and the Patriarchal Cross/Orthodox Cross showed up in my frequently used emojis.  I have never used any of these.  There must be a link between what you read online and your frequently used emojis.

Comment: It's possible, but I would tend away from anecdotes here.